# VBA: Extract string from HTML tag

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to pull this bit as a string `fileKey=2945596` in this part.

```
<a href='javascript:OpenDownloadWindow("../Common/FileDownloader.aspx?fileKey=2945596")'>Work Order Inquiry - Work Order</a>
```

When I use

```
Right(IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvExtract").getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText, 10)
```

It Returns this string `Work Order`. I belive it it because if the `.innerText` part but I havent a clue how to pull from the javascript link.

Comment: use `innerhtml`

Comment: `.innerHTML` returns the same string.

Comment: set what you are getting to a variable, and then look in the locals window to see what it contains.